# How to create a newsletter subscription form in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, newsletter, newsletter2go

How can I create a registration form and a newsletter for users who sign up using the Newsletter plugin? I'm having trouble sending a test email and creating an email marketing campaign with the contact list obtained through the form.

I'm developing a website in WordPress and I'd like to create a feature that allows users to subscribe by providing their name and email address in a subscription form. The goal is for these users to receive emails with updates about new posts on my website. I'm using the Newsletter plugin for WordPress, but I'm experiencing issues when sending the email to the user. I receive a message saying that the email was sent, but the end user doesn't receive it.